Is a 2 step cdk deployment necessary for aws cognito custom domain?
I am creating a user pool with an app client and a custom domain using AWS cognito. As I was writing my CDK code I ran into a circular dependency when creating a custom domain for my app client auth.
In simple words: the code that adds the new custom domain expects the ARecord to exist, but that same code is the one that gives access to the cloudfront domain the ARecord should point to.
Example code:
const userPoolDomain = userPool.addDomain('cognito-domain', {
            customDomain: { domainName: getAuthApiRecordName(props.stageName), certificate },
        })

new ARecord(this, 'cognito-alias-record', {
            zone: authHostedZone,
            target: RecordTarget.fromAlias(new UserPoolDomainTarget(userPoolDomain)),
            recordName: getAuthApiRecordName(props.stageName),
})

Based on the cognito documentation and what people on stackoverflow are saying, I get a sense that the solution is to do 2 cdk deployments. First deploy with a dummy ARecord that points somewhere else, and create the custom domain. Then, in a second deployment, point the ARecord to the cloudfront target that was created in the first deployment.
Am i correct that this is the suggested way of doing it? If so, wouldn't it make sense to allow access to the cloudfront target before the creation of a custom domain to avoid this circular dependency? It can definitely be circumnavigated, but it makes the process of replicating stages across accounts clunkier.

I was wrong about the issue at hand. The problem is not a "chicken and egg" one. After struggling with this a bit i went back to reading the cognito AWS docs also linked above and found this requirement:
"A web domain that you own. Its parent domain must have a valid DNS A record. You can assign any value to this record. The parent may be the root of the domain, or a child domain that is one step up in the domain hierarchy. For example, if your custom domain is auth.xyz.example.com, Amazon Cognito must be able to resolve xyz.example.com to an IP address. To prevent accidental impact on customer infrastructure, Amazon Cognito doesn't support the use of top-level domains (TLDs) for custom domains. For more information see Domain Names."
So I ended up creating a hosted zone "auth.example.com", and add a dummy ARecord pointing to a bogus IP address: "auth.example.com" -> "1.1.1.1".
Then I could create the cognito user pool, a custom domain name such as "alpha.auth.example.com", and the correspective ARecord. Without needing 2 cdk deployments or anything special. Here is the example code:
// First create a hosted zone for "auth.example.com". Here i assume you already own "example.com"

// create a dummy ARecord to satisfy cognito requirements
new ARecord(this, 'dummy-auth-a-record', {
    zone: authHostedZone,
    target: RecordTarget.fromIpAddresses('1.1.1.1'),
    recordName: "auth.example.com",
})

// create user pool as you wish

// add custom domain
const userPoolDomain = userPool.addDomain('cognito-domain', {
    customDomain: { domainName: "alpha.auth.example.com", certificate },
})

new ARecord(this, 'cognito-alias-record', {
    zone: authHostedZone,
    target: RecordTarget.fromAlias(new UserPoolDomainTarget(userPoolDomain)),
    recordName: "alpha.auth.example.com",
})

